# Importing new column from .xlsx into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a dataset which started with 10 columns and imported to PowerBI and all fine.

Two further columns have been added but how can I bring these in without loading the spreadsheet for a second time? I've lots of calculations and other tables linking to the initial import but need these two additional columns to show.

I've seen solutions for .csv's where in Advanced Editor you alter the number of columns, but this is a multitab spreadsheet and I'd prefer to keep it in .xslx but add the other two columns.

Comment: Just refresh data in power bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding columns, save excel file. In power bi go to `Data View -> Home -> Refresh`. That will add columns to data sheet in power bi

Comment: This works on a test file, but not on the one I was trying to add columns too. Odd.